# Difficulty with Converting a WebSite to Web Application and Testing

Tags: asp.net, wpf, web-applications

This is not as straight forward as I had hoped.

I created a Web Site project on my development machine using the Visual Studio C# template for a WebSite Project. (Visual studio 2010 .net 4.0). The project name is C:\Nova5\WebSite3. It consists solely of:

1. the Bin subdirectory
2. Nova.svc file
3. web.config file

It has been tested to run correctly by:

1. Setting the website as the startup project, then
2. Run Debug-->Start Debugging

When tested, the NovaDataService information page is correctly displayed. It also correctly works when used through my client project.

I followed the recommended procedure described at
[Walkthrough: Converting a Web Site Project to a Web Application Project in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476(v=vs.100).aspx) to covert the Web Site to a Web Application.

I now have the following problems and/or difficulties:

1. If I use the recommended procedure for testing the web site:
      -- File | Open | Web Site
      -- Build Web Site -- Start Debugging

   I get the Error: The type 'Nova5WCFServiceLibrary.NovaDataService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in 
               the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.
2. Since, I think, the WebSite does work, I skipped this error and moved on to the next part of the article. The next issue (?) is there is no App_Code file in the WebSite.  Is this necessary?  If it is necessary, how should I create it? Or do I need to create another WebSite project from its template just to have it?
3. I did not copy the Nova.svc  nor the web.config from the WebSite to the Web Application as none of the references I read indicated to do so. Should I copy these files to the Web Application as well?
4. I now used the "Convert to Web Application" on the Web Application project and recompiled the solution. Everybody is happy. No errors reported. So how do I now test the Web Application project on my development machine (which also has the client application) ?

TIA

Comment: `WPF WebSite` - there's no such thing. WPF is a desktop UI technology. I have no freakin idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @HighCore Sorry for my confusion. The WebSite was written in Visual Studio 2010, using the C# Website template. I used WPF for the client application on the desktop. Thanks for the correction. Any idea how to convert the WebSite project as stated above to a Web Application? Thanks for any help.